# Delete rows across multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP and MySQL. I need to do a query:

```
DELETE FROM db1.players WHERE acc NOT IN (SELECT id FROM db2.accounts)
```

The problem is, that db1 and db2 are located on different servers. What is the fastest solution for such problem?

To be precise: I'm using 2 connections, so I think I can't use one query for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will either have to save the list you want to an array and compare it with the other database

or

You can make a [federated table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) and make it seem like the query is running on 1 database.

Comment: federated table ...that's interesting , +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the fastest, but I would create a temporary table on db2 containing account ids, export that table to db1 and run the query there.

For the exporting part you can either use mysql builtin export/import functions, where you would have to consider finding an unused table name or use the CSV-[export](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)/[import](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) of mysql.

If the expected number of results from the inner query is reasonably small, you can transfer from within PHP using strings:

```
$ids = query($db1, "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM accounts");
query($db2, "DELETE FROM players WHERE acc NOT IN ($ids)");
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `database.table.field` should actually work in MySQL.
But I guess you've to run the query directly on the MySQL server. Not sure about this.

Have you tried the following?

```
DELETE FROM db1.players WHERE db1.players.acc NOT IN (SELECT db2.accounts.id FROM db2.accounts)
```

Or did I get you wrong and the two databases are not on the same server?
Have a look here: http://www.dottedidesign.com/node/14

Comment: According to a comment behind that link, you can do e.g. "exec sp_addlinkedserver [192.168.2.123]", then you can e.g. "select * from [192.168.2.123].[pubs].[dbo].[authors]".

Comment: 'sp_addlinkedserve' is a MSSQL procedure, there is no equivalent in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like:

- create temporary table for the ids on the local server
- statement to fetch ids from remote server
- prepared statement to insert ids into temp. table
- transfering ids remote->local
- DELETE using the temp.table

```
<?php
$pdoRemote = new PDO('mysql:host=somewhere.else;dbname=foo', '...', '...');
$pdoRemote->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdoLocal = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bar', '...', '...');
$pdoLocal->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$pdoLocal->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE remoteIds ( id int )'); // maybe engine=heap
$stmtLocal = $pdoLocal->prepare('INSERT INTO remoteIds (id) VALUES (:id)');
$stmtLocal->bindParam(':id', $id);

foreach( $pdoRemote->query('SELECT id FROM accounts') as $row ) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $stmtLocal->execute();
}
unset($pdoRemote);
```

Answer (score 0):

To query multiple databases, on different servers, using a single query you can use [federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html).

You could also use replication, or temporary tables.  This way you're accessing the databases on the same server.

The only other alternative I can think of would be to use [MySQL Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy) to parse your query into 2 or more queries.

I think I'm right in saying that you can't do it the way you are be able to with MSSQL using the [`sp_addlinkedserver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259589(SQL.80).aspx) procedure.

You might be better using two queries.